# Haddop FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath problem

Tags: java, amazon-s3, hadoop, amazon-emr

I'm having issues with setting the output format for a Hadoop job.

When running my code with Amazon EMR I'm getting this to stderr:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HftpFileSystem cannot access its superinterface org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.TokenAspect$TokenManagementDelegator
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.loadFileSystems(FileSystem.java:3272)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3407)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:486)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(FileOutputFormat.java:178)
    at Main.main(Main.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

while `Main.main(Main.java:68)` is this:

```
Job firstMapReduceJob = Job.getInstance(conf1, "firstMapReduce");
.
.
.
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(firstMapReduceJob, new Path("s3n://bucket-name/test"));
firstMapReduceJob.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
```

My bucket exists and I have a folder named "test" inside.
I can see my cluster on Amazon EMR so I have all of the aws credentials set up alright.
Will be glad to provide any more needed code.

Edit: hadoop version is 2.7.2:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use Spark to read from S3?

Comment: @OneCricketeer No specific reason, I wrote this job to learn how to use Hadoop and EMR. Actually I had a problem in my POM, problem is not fixed but I would still like an explanation for the cause of this exception. Thanks for trying!

Comment: Spark uses Hadoop libraries and can be deployed in EMR as well, so I didn't understand your point. If you have fixed something in the POM, please [edit] the question. Also worth mentioning that you don't show any `hadoop-aws` dependency here